# How to get ApplicationContext in Micronaut CLI application into Httpclient class?

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I am running a Micronaut CLI application via Picocli runner wanted to use applicationContext for injecting/getting the bean during application execution.

```
@HttpRetryable
@Client("SERVICE_ID")
interface TestHttpClient {

}
@Inject
lateinit var applicationContext: ApplicationContext

private class AuthenticationFilter() : HttpClientFilter {
    // calling appcontext here
    println("appContext is Running " + appContext.isRunning)
}
```

But getting this error on the execution

````
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property applicationContext has not been initialized```
How this can be fixed ?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property needs to be in the `AuthenticationFilter` class. That class should be annotated with `jakarta.inject.Singleton` and should not be private